# how to create an iphone-like search for android

Tags: java, android, search, ios-simulator

How create an iphone-like search for android?

I could not alter the standard search android. Is it possible?
I decided to make a my custom widget.

Have any ideas how best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented iphone-like search in the form widget, who need a widget can download it from sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/search-widget/

If you have any questions, I will be glad to answer them.

Comment: Pordon?
Can you look at
http://search-widget.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=search-widget/search-widget;a=commit;h=5529f9b751a8846f05e13ee3ac7a9d01656574f8
or
https://github.com/netcook/search-widget
?

Comment: Seems sourceforge remove it :(

Comment: I think the best use the resource for find the same solution https://android-arsenal.com/tag/208?sort=created